# Иерархическое дерево на php mysql

Tags: дерево, php, mysql

Делал когда то давно комментарии в виде дерева
использовал таблицу с 2 id

```
id - автоинкримент
parent_id - родительский id к которому относится комментарий, если родителя нет то 0
```

тут как бы все понятно все просто

но как то я услышал от программиста что в дереве применяется не 2 параметра как у меня а 5

объясните кто знает что это за параметры и для чего они нужны

Answer (score 1):

Да хоть 10.

Самое распространенное - вводят "path", "level", "weight"
path - строка, где перечисленны все родители данного нода через какой-то разделяющий символ. Например: /1/4/77/131/ Позволяет выбрать поддерево одним простым запросом

```
where path like '/1/4/%'
```

level - вроде понятно.
weight - параметр для произвольной сортировки одноранговых элементов.